# DDD: how to query multi aggregate root by state

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have an aggregate root called Scene like below, I need to fetch all the active scene to do some business logic. I want to know where do I fetch these aggregates? Query repository? Or query database then use factory to build these aggregate roots? In my project, I use CQRS by using the same database.

```
public class Scene extends Entity {
  private SceneId sceneId;
  private ConditionId conditionId;
  private Area area;
  private Date startEffectTime;
  private Date endEffectTime;
  private boolean active;
...
public methods...
...
```

}

Comment: "I need to fetch all the active scene to do some business logic" - What kind of business logic has to be execute? Read calculations or state transitions?

Comment: Customer's info should match an active Scene (match method is one of method of the Scene) , and then use the Scene to execute a call, and return the response.

Comment: Since you are using CQRS, it would make sense to separate the read side (Query) from the write side (Command). With this in mind, you can consider creating a query layer that provides data in the format required. Would you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: Say a customer comes in my system, and I need use the customer's info to match an active scene and then use the scene's method to calculate a reply return to the customer. So first I should find all active scenes from repository and then use customer's info to match one, then execute a scene's method to calculate an answer. In cqrs, where should I write the "query" code? Use Query Model?(I think it all about representation). Use Command Model? it returns void.  I am so confused; @CPerson thanks